# Bootstrap 2 Collapse Icon Does Not Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following piece of code. When the page loads, the data in the collapse hides and I am left with the down arrow which is the icon-chevron-down.

When I click on this icon, I need it to change to the corresponding 'up' icon, i.e. the icon-chevron-up icon.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Example of Twitter Bootstrap Collapse Methods</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div class="widget-box transparent">
                                        <div class="widget-header widget-header-flat">
                                            <h4 class="lighter">
                                                <i class="icon-star orange"></i>
                                                Dashboard
                                            </h4>

                                            <div class="widget-toolbar" style="margin-left:30px">
                                                <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#summaryData">
                                                    <i class="icon-chevron-down"></i>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="widget-body collapse in" id="summaryData">
                                                Test me
                                            </div><!-- /widget-body -->
                                        </div><!-- /widget-box -->
</body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
  $('#summaryData').collapse('hide');

        $('#summaryData').on('show hide', function (e) {
        if(!$(this).is(e.target))return; 
        $('#summaryData').toggleClass('icon-arrow-up icon-arrow-down', 200);
    });
        });
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

summary data doesn't contain the icon element, so the toggle code will never be reached.  A quick workaround would be adding this click handling function:

```
  $(document.body).on('click', '.icon-chevron-down, .icon-chevron-up', function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('icon-chevron-up icon-chevron-down');
  });
```